# How to prove the Taylor series identity

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

How to prove the following identity:
$(1-t)^{-L}=\sum_{j\geq 0}
\binom{j+L-1}{L-1}t^j$.

I will appreciate for your helpful suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Refer to the [**Binomial Series**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)

$$(1 + x)^\alpha = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \; {\alpha \choose k} \; x^k   $$

for the special case with negative integer exponent.

Comment: good. I Get it. Thank you very much

Comment: @Dr.Jacob.Z.Lee You are welcome! Bye